# Floating Point Multiplication

Tags: math, floating-point, binary, multiplication, ieee-754

I got this problem I have to solve where I have to multiply to floating point numbers (16 bit), but I have no way of double checking it. Any help is immensely appreciated.

Floating Point A: 0 11000 0111000000 
Floating Point B: 0 11010 1011000000

I calculate the exponents:

A: 24-15=9
B: 26-15=11

Calculate mantissas (a & b):

(2^9*b) * (2^11*b) = 2^9+11 * (a*b) + 2^20 * (a*b)

Overflow, so I increase exponent of A to sane as B(11).

Then I shift mantissa of A in accordance with the calculation:

1.0111 > 0.10111 > 0.010111.

Then I multiply to get mantissa.

```
                    0.010111
                  * 1.101100
                     0000000
                   0000000
                 0010111
               0010111
             0000000
           0010111
         0010111_____
       0.100110110100
```

I shift again.

0.100110110100 < 1.00110110100

Decrease exponent by 1, so it's 10.

Sign is 0, so it's positive number.

Answer: 0 01010 00110110100.

Is it correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is impossible to understand what you are doing from the line `(2^9*b) * (2^11*b) = 2^9+11 * (a*b) + 2^20 * (a*b)`. You do not need to equalize the exponents to multiply: this is what you do to align the significands for **addition** and **subtraction**.

Comment: When doing this sort of work, I strongly recommend obtaining or writing a converter from the floating point format to decimal numbers. It makes checking much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [binary16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary16)

Is it correct?: No.

Both "mantissas" or fraction need to include an *implied* bit as its not the minimum exponent.  So `.1011000000` becomes `1.1011000000`.

Instead `1.01 1100 0000` * `1.10 1100 0000` = `10.0110 1101 0000 0000 0000`

The change in exponent is something to consider after the multiplication, in addition to rounding.

Shift right the product `1.0011 0110 1000 0000 0000 0` and +1 to the unbiased exponents 9 + 11 + 1 --> 21.

Round the product to 10 fraction bits
`1.0011 0110 1000 0000 0000 0`
`1.0011 0110 10`

Rebuild result
sign 0^0 = `0`
biased exponent 21 + 15 = 36 = `100100`, which overflows. @Yves Daoust
fraction = `0011 0110 10`.

Overflow is typically set to INF `0 11111 0000000000 = infinity`

Have not doubled check my work yet.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

- you don't account for the implicit 1 as the leftmost bit of the mantissas: 1.0111000000 * 1.1011000000,
- the exponent overflows and the result just cannot be represented [had the exponent underflown, you could have denormalized].